# Adding New Contacts but they Disappear

Tags: iphone, contacts

When I add a contact from my keypad screen and save it the contact doesn't show up in my contacts list.  But if they call or text me it recognizes the contact.  Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: What version of iOS are you on? And follow these steps first and then let me know if it still doesn't work: Open "Contacts.app",Press "Groups" button, Select Show "All Contacts."

Comment: Tara, I will repost this as an answer for other "Googlers" to see.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Open `Contacts.app`
2. Press the `Groups button` in the top left corner.

[image]

3. Select `Show All Contacts`.

[image]